# How to enable a robot to ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I would like to enable my robot with ROS target.

But I can not find any information about that.
What is the procedure to follow?
Can you help me about this question?

Sincerely.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164161/how-to-enable-a-robot-to-ros/) by [RoboE](https://answers.ros.org/users/13546/roboe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This presentation by Melonee Wise at RosCon 2013](http://vimeo.com/66966974) on "ROSifying Robots" and the [associated slides](http://roscon.ros.org/2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ROSCon2013_rosify_robot.pdf) should be helpful in providing some first information and ideas on where to look next.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2